# Getting error compiling C++ code (Invalid Conversion)

Tags: c++, file, file-io, compiler-errors, ifstream

I get **invalid conversion from `void*` to `FILE*`** error while compiling below file. It takes name of file as parameter and tries to open the file and if file opens it returns the
**file pointer** otherwise returns **`NULL`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

FILE* open(const char filename[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    FILE* fp = open("test.txt");
}

FILE* open(const char filename[])
{
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open(filename);
    if(myFile.is_open())
        return myFile;
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The conversion from NULL to FILE* is the least of your problems. You're also converting from std::ifstream to FILE*, which are entirely different structures not to mention that one is a local variable and the other is a pointer. Additionally, you're not returning a value from main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "open" claims to return "FILE*" but actually returns an ifstream.

Note that "open" conflicts with the standard library's "open" function, so this may also be a poor choice of function name.

You can either return an ifstream or you can take one as a parameter to initialize.

```
bool openFile(ifstream& file, const char* filename)
{
    file.open(filename);
    return !file.is_open();
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    ifstream file;
    if (!openFile(file, "prefixRanges.txt"))
        // we have a problem

}
```

If you really want to return the file from the function:

```
ifstream openFile(const char* filename)
{
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open(filename);
    return myFile;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    ifstream myFile = openFile("prefixRanges.txt");
    if (!myFile.is_open())
        // that's no moon.
}
```

As this shows, though, unless "openFile" is going to do something more, it's a bit redundant. Compare:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    ifstream file("prefixRanges.txt");
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // other stuff
}
```

If what you actually need, though, is a FILE*, you have to write C-like code like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

FILE* openFile(const char* filename)
{
    FILE* fp = std::fopen(filename, "r");
    return fp;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    FILE* fp = openFile("prefixRanges.txt");
    if (!fp) {
        // that's no moon, or file
    }
}
```

or just

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    FILE* fp = std::fopen("prefixRanges.txt", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        // that's no moon, or file
    }
}
```

Comment: i might do this but since its my school assignment i need to return a FILE pointer else it will not pass the tester.

Comment: @Nakib Then you probably want to use fopen from cstdio (see last example)

Comment: Nope - the C standard library is still available to us - you can #include <stdio.h> if you really want to, but there's also <cstdio> which encapsulates the functions into the "std::" namespace, and that's a better practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return `std::ifstream` object as `FILE*`. Try to change:

```
FILE* open(const char filename[])
```

to

```
std::ifstream open(const char* filename)
```

and instead of checking whether `NULL` has been returned, use `std::ifstream::is_open()`:

```
std::ifstream is = open("myfile.txt");
if (!is.is_open()) {
    // file hasn't been opened properly
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`myFile` is a `ifstream` object.

You can't return it as a `FILE` pointer

Also you can't return `std::ifstream` as it doesn't have a copy constructor

You can pass it by reference

```
 bool openFile(ifstream& fin, const char *filename) {
  fin.open(filename);
  return fin.is_open();
}
```

In main

```
ifstream fin;
if(!openFile(fin, "input.txt")){

}
```

Comment: what changes i need to make in order to return it as FILE pointer

Comment: @Nakib use the standard C library instead of the STL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
std::ifstream open(const char* filename)
```

instead of

```
FILE* open(const char filename[])
```

Also try to `return` some value from your `main` function.